# ActiveRecord: Create Duplicates ActiveRecord Results

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'd like to duplicate several records on demand. The records seed a new user with example records that they will likely customize over time. I started with the following:

```
MaintenanceSchedule.find_each do |schedule|
  @example=MaintenanceSchedule.new(schedule)
  @example.org_id=current_user.active_org.id
  @example.save
end
```

It was a long shot, and it fails as expected on the second line:

```
undefined method `stringify_keys' for #<MaintenanceSchedule:0x4c4d450>
```

Never mind the error. What's the best way to duplicate records?

Answer (score 0):

The following does the trick, although I'd be happy to find a more efficient way:

```
MaintenanceSchedule.find_each do |schedule|
  @example=schedule.dup
  @example.org_id=current_user.active_org.id
  @example.save
end
```